# Filling data from one website into another website in php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I try to filling some data from one website into another website, which both website are not holding in the same server and I have no right to access into the back end of the other website.

For example:
I created a website that will collect the following data from the user
- name
- telephone number
- address

Then I have to pass those data (auto fill-in so that I do not have to manually enter the same data) into the other independent website for user information checking (t0 make sure that the address, telephone and address is the valid data).

Does anyone know how can I do it in php/javascript? Any example or tutorial can show?

Answer (score 1):

I would use JSONP to move data between different domains and use JQuery's getJSON method to make a call to the server. The PHP file should return the data in proper format and the client should be able to read it using JQuery.

Here is a sample:
**The server-side PHP code**

```
    <?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

// Create a generic object.
// Assign it the property 'message' - the feedback message we want the user to see.
 $rtnjsonobj->message = "You got an AJAX response via JSONP from another site!";

// Wrap and write a JSON-formatted object with a function call, using the supplied value of parm 'callback' in the URL:
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';    

?>
```

**Get data from client**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#jsonpbtn").click(function() {
    var surl =  "http://www.otherdomain.com/abovepage.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(surl,  function(rtndata) {
        alert(rtndata.message);
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is exactly cross-site scripting (XSS). All modern browsers will prevent you from executing any front-end (JS) script on any url which is not in the original domain.

You can try passing GET values into the page and if the devs built handles into their PHP for that, you might be able to populate the fields. I highly doubt this would work because of the massive security hole it would expose.

I don't know what it is your trying to do at the end of the day, but **BE VERY CAREFUL**. XSS is an exploit and there's a good chance you could get into trouble for it.